# Remove Renderings From Layout Through Content Editor

Tags: sitecore-client

I want to allow the content editor to remove broken renderings. I am aware that there is a remove broken links tool, but it's too broad. It will remove ALL broken links across any site the the DB. In this case, I just want to remove a few specific ones.

Currently, the content editor is able to access the layout and edit the individual renderings. However, is there a way to delete them? The only way I can think of is to display its raw values and edit them directly:

[image]

This is very easy to mess up and is not something we want the content editor to do themselves.

Is there a graphical way to delete an individual rendering from the layout details? We are on version 7.5.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Content Editor go to Presentation tab and click Details

You will be listed on each device the layout associated with it as well as all the renderings. You can click on the Edit button and on the Controls tab on the left you will see the list of all renderings.

You can select the ones you and to delete and click on the Remove button(highlighted bellow) on the right
[image]